# Add marker infoWindow to Mapbox annotation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, mapbox

I've tried to add a custom `UIView` as the infoWindow of my `MGLAnnotation` but I can't understand how can I do it.

I've tried for days but the closest I succeeded is to take my custom `UIView` and add it as a `InfoWindow` but really small (I think it was 500px width and 100px height).

How can I take the full size `UIView` and to add it as a infoWindow to the annotation?

Thank you!

Comment: Since `MGLAnnotation` has no `infoWindow` property, it's not clear what you're asking. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: If you’re referring to the callout view, see this example: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/custom-callout/

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes, I want to replace the basic view that shown when you click on an annotation to a custom UIView, is it more clear now?

Comment: @friedbunny I've tried to understand that guide but after hours of trying I can't understand how can I connect a custom UIView as the callout. Can you please help me with an example? I'll be so thankful.

Comment: The custom callout view API is more complicated than it needs to be, but it’s also not clear what your issue is. If others are to help you, you should be more specific about: 1. What you’re trying to accomplish, 2. What the problem is that you’re encountering, and 3. What you have already tried.

Comment: @friedbunny I have a custom XIB connected to a subclass of UIView and I want it to be the custom callout, that's what I'm trying to accomplish. I've tried this guide you provided but the best I could get with it was to do there exact same thing they show on this guide, they don't show how to connect a custom UIView to the callout. Can you please share with me a short example to help me understand it better? Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

See this example: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/custom-callout/

Specifically, look for the implementation of [`-[MGLMapViewDelegate mapView:calloutViewForAnnotation:]`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.3.3/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:calloutViewForAnnotation:).

If you’re loading it from a XIB, you will have to do extra work to initialize the view, but the concept is the same.

Comment: I've copy-pasted the entire code from this guide, but when I try to replace the `mainBody` with `Self` custom view the callout doesn't being shown when I click the annotation

Comment: I've succeeded to load the view (I've created another "ControllerView" and set my custom view as the `mainBody`), but now the frame is really weird (all of the screen) and I can't understand how can I set it to the correct size